# Having the same orientation for a group of images

Tags: python, function, image-processing, computer-vision

Say that we have a group of images, how can we have them all with the same orientation.

Should we start with a reference image and base our orientation for the other images based on that image?

Are there libraries or functions one can use in `Python` for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please make clear what you mean by image orientation? Example images would probably help.

Comment: Like if an image was rotated 45 degrees, all the images would have that rotation. Thanks.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: how do you know an image is rotated 45 degrees? digital images usually don't have an orientation